# MVC - check whether user accessing the page has logged into the site

Tags: asp.net-mvc

1. how to check that the user who is accessing the page is already logged into the site
2. i want to keep some data - like permission's related to the user who has logged into the site - where to store this data
   should i use - session for both of these information?

Comment: What authentication mechanism do you use to log in the user?  The simple answer is to check the state of that mechanism.  For example, if you're using the default membership mechanisms then `Request.IsAuthenticated` can tell you if the user is logged in, `User.Identity` can tell you who they are, etc.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you can use the standard ASP.NET infrastructure about Membership and Roles.

Assuming you're checking for these inside a controller action, you have the User property that can help you:

```
if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) {
    // user is logged-in
}
```

The second question depends on what kind of data. If you're talking about permissions, it sounds you might be able to avoid storing anything at all and just resort to the Roles provider for identifying which user has which permissions.

Comment: i don't want to use "Standard ASP.Net" infrastructure. i want to load permission to somewhere (session seems to be right place) for storing permission and while loading page just validate the access permission against the loaded permission.

Comment: Any particular reason why you don't want to use it? It solves the problem you're describing and it's pretty much standard.